# Receive data for side menu in all views in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am just getting started with Laravel and I don't know how to do this.

I have a tipical side menu that will be in almost every view like so:

[Side Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDxKM.png)

In my index view I don't have problem because I do this:

```
            @foreach($lastRecipes as $lastRecipe)
                <div class="side-lastRecipes">
                    {{lastRecipe->name}}
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

With this in the route / controller:

[IndexController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR4AQ.png)

Do I have to make this queries to the db for EVERY get view with "with"?

```
        return view('welcome')
    ->with("lastRecipes",$lastRecipes);
```

I thought about calling this method getSideMenu from other controllers but I read that laravel has no static functions and you have to use Facades, but I don't know if this is a good practise or there is a best way to deal with this side menu.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class add following code in your in `boot()` function:

```
\View::share('key', 'value');
```

In your case `key` should be `lastRecipes` and `value` should be that what you want to share.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I had to add "use App\Recipe;" at the top in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit ambiguous, because every controller has to deal with a single responsibility principle , I mean f. Example you have HomeController wich render home page , including partials such as navbar , sidebars footer etc.. so you just have one controller who render all pages... ( Also known as FrontController ),Imagine HomeController has index method who render home page , and contact method who renders contact , and aboutus method who render about us sections. The responsibility of HomeController is just to render pages.
So in case you have contacts forms in your pages who sends data , so you will have a ContactFormsController who will get the request and for index you will have a method , for contact you will have a method and so on...
As you said your are beginning with Laravel , so is a great PHP frameworks that do a lot of stuff for you behind the scenes , answering your question , it practically will not affect to the performance ( if it is your question ) because you have a Eloquent cache and a blade cache so don't worry.
In other hand there's a feature that can help if you need to share "partial or pieces" to every page is displayed : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers , but anyway I discourage use it right now , because you're learning and need to still play before think in other things.